# When is an open subset of an affine variety, affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I will call $X$ an affine variety if $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, where $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra ($k$ algebraically closed field) with no nilpotents. Also $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is the maximal spectrum, or $\mathrm{Spec}(A) = \mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-alg}}(A,k)$. (I'm following the notation of Kempf's Algebraic Varieties).

In this sense, a principal open subset of $X$ at $a\in A$, say $D(a)$, is affine since it is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(A_{(a)})$. More generally (if I haven't made a mistake anywhere), if $S$ is a multiplicative set in $A$, then there exists an open set $U\subset X$ such that $U\simeq \mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$.

I'm asking if the reverse is true? I mean can I say:

> An open $U\subset X$ is affine if and only if $U=\mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$, i.e. the maximal spectrum of a localization of $A$?

I want to know quite generally how can we tell if an open set is affine (like $D(a)$) and when it is not (like $\mathbb{A}^2\setminus\{0\}\subset\mathbb{A}^2$). What property stops some open sets from being affine? In other words:

> When is an open subset of an affine variety, affine?

Comment: I think you have some confusion. For example, if $A$ is an integral domain, $K$ its fraction field, then $K=S^{-1}A$ where $S=A-\{0\}$, but we do not usually say that $\mathrm{Spec}(K)$ is open in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. The reverse as you state is not true. As a typical example, take $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw)$ and the open set to be the complement of the closed set defined by $x=z=0$. There are simpler examples (for example positive genus affine curves).

Comment: I see! I didn't exactly prove it just made a few arguments in my mind. Thank you. But what about the second question?

Comment: I hope you realized that the second question can not have a reasonable answer after my comments, in such generality. If you ask what you would like to happen, may be one can try.

Comment: One necessary condition is that the complement of $U$ must be codimension 1.